# Racket equivalents of python's __repr__ and __str__?

Tags: oop, racket

In python objects, overriding the methods `__repr__` and `__str__` of an object allows one to provide "unambiguous" and "human-readable" representations of the object, respectively. How does one achieve similar behavior in Racket?

I came across the `printable<%>` interface [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/objectprinting.html), which seems like it should be usable for this purpose, but I haven't been able to get it to work quite as I expect it to. Building on the standard "fish" example from the docs:

```
(define fish%
  (class* object% (printable<%>)
    (init size) ; initialization argument
    (super-new) ; superclass initialization
    ;; Field
    (define current-size size)

    ;; Public methods
    (define/public (get-size)
      current-size)
    (define/public (grow amt)
      (set! current-size (+ amt current-size)))
    (define/public (eat other-fish)
      (grow (send other-fish get-size)))

    ;; implement printable interface
    (define/public (custom-print port quoting-depth)
      (print "Print called!"))
    (define/public (custom-write port)
      (print "Write called!"))
    (define/public (custom-display port)
      (print "Display called!"))))
```

This is the output I get:

```
> (define f (new fish% [size 10]))
> f
"Display called!""Display called!""Print called!"
> (print f)
"Write called!""Print called!"
> (display f)
"Display called!""Display called!"
> (write f)
"Write called!""Write called!"
>
```

So the question is threefold:

1. Why does it behave this way, i.e. with the multiple methods being invoked on an apparently singular rendering of the object?
2. What should the methods custom-print, custom-write, and custom-display evaluate to? Should they simply return a string, or should they actually entail the side effect of printing, writing, or displaying, as the case may be? E.g. should the custom-write method invoke the `write` function internally?
3. Is this the right construct to use for this purpose at all? If not, is there one / what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for

> 1. Why does it behave this way, i.e. with the multiple methods being invoked on an apparently singular rendering of the object?

You have accidently used `print` in `write`, so writing the value, will first print the value.

```
(define/public (custom-write port)
   (print "Write called!"))
```

A similar problem is present in `display`.

Also remember to print/write/display to the proper port.

Try

```
#lang racket
(define fish%
  (class* object% (printable<%>)
    (init size) ; initialization argument
    (super-new) ; superclass initialization
    ;; Field
    (define current-size size)

    ;; Public methods
    (define/public (get-size)
      current-size)
    (define/public (grow amt)
      (set! current-size (+ amt current-size)))
    (define/public (eat other-fish)
      (grow (send other-fish get-size)))

    ;; implement printable interface
    (define/public (custom-print port quoting-depth)
      (print (~a "Print " current-size "\n") port))
    (define/public (custom-write port)
      (write (~a "Write " current-size "\n") port))
    (define/public (custom-display port)
      (display (~a "Display " current-size "\n") port))))
```

In the repl you will see:

```
> (define f (new fish% [size 10]))
> f
"Print 10\n"
> (display f)
Display 10
> (write f)
"Write 10\n"
```

Comment: "You have accidently used print in write, so writing the value, will first print the value." -- the print statement there was actually meant for tracing purposes, it is just printing a string and not the object itself. Does it still end up hitting the print method on the object? Also the order of methods hit in the tracing output don't seem to line up with that hypothesis. At the same time your code totally works! Do you think it has something to do with the port?

Comment: If in the `write` method call the system `print`, then the system `print` will invoke the `print` method. Not 100% about the ports, but it is important to use the port, otherwise all output will happen to the standard output port (and newer to files, standard error and other places).

Comment: Makes sense. I do find that using the port explicitly in my original code causes the duplication to go away. Even though you addressed point #1 from my question, your answer actually addresses all 3 points raised. Marking as accepted!

Comment: @soegaard I don't think it's correct that "if in the write method call the system print, then the system print will invoke the print method." The original custom-write implementation calls `print` on a string, which shouldn't invoke any methods on your `fish%` instance. I believe the duplicated output is because DrRacket uses the pretty-printer, which does some writing and printing to temporary ports.

Comment: @LiberalArtist What happens using racket in the terminal?

Comment: @soegaard I'm adding an answer with an illustration.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer has already helped you find the problem in your code—you need to use the port given as an argument, not the implicit `(current-output-port)`—but the explanation isn't quite right. To tackle your questions in reverse order:

> 3. Is this the right construct to use for this purpose at all? If not, is there one / what is it?

Yes, `printable<%>` is the right construct to use to customize printing of a class-based object. More generally, a struct type that is not a class can customize printing for instance through the `gen:custom-write` generic interface or the low-level `prop:custom-write` struct type property, which is used to implement `printable<%>`.

> 2. What should the methods custom-print, custom-write, and custom-display evaluate to? Should they simply return a string, or should they actually entail the side effect of printing, writing, or displaying, as the case may be? E.g. should the custom-write method invoke the write function internally?

The methods should actually do the side-effect of performing IO on the port they are given as an argument. They should use the corresponding function (e.g. `write` for `custom-write`, `print` for `custom-print`) internally for recursively printing/writing/displaying values in fields. On the other hand, when directly emitting particular characters, they should generally use functions like `write-char`, `write-string`, or `printf`. [The docs for `gen:custom-write`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Printer_Extension.html) give an example of a tuple datatype that prints as `<1, 2, "a">`: it uses `write-string` for the angle-brackets and commas, but recursive `print`/`write`/`display` for the elements of the tuple.

> 1. Why does it behave this way, i.e. with the multiple methods being invoked on an apparently singular rendering of the object?

This is the most involved part of your question. Printing in Racket is customizable through several hooks: for a few examples, see [`current-print`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._current-print))), [`port-write-handler`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._port-write-handler))), [`global-port-print-handler`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._global-port-print-handler))), and [`make-tentative-pretty-print-output-port`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pretty-print.html#(def._((lib._racket%2Fpretty..rkt)._make-tentative-pretty-print-output-port))). Many of these customization hooks use intermediate ports in the process of producing output.

One thing that is *not* a part of the explanation is the fact that you used `print` in your implementation, particularly as `print` is bound to the normal Racket function by lexical scope, not to a method of your object.

As an illustration, consider the following adaptation of your example, which reports to the `(current-output-port)` the identity of the port given as an argument to the method:

```lisp
#lang racket

(define report
  (let ([next-id 0]
        [id-cache (make-hash)])
    (λ (op port)
      (printf "~a ~a ~v\n"
              op
              (hash-ref id-cache
                        port
                        (λ ()
                          (define id next-id)
                          (hash-set! id-cache port id)
                          (set! next-id (add1 next-id))
                          id))
              port))))

(define fish%
  (class* object% (printable<%>)
    (super-new)
    ;; implement printable interface
    (define/public (custom-print port quoting-depth)
      (report "custom-print  " port))
    (define/public (custom-write port)
      (report "custom-write  " port))
    (define/public (custom-display port)
      (report "custom-display" port))))

(define f (new fish%))

f

(print f)
(newline)

(display f)
(newline)

(write f)
```

In DrRacket, this generates the output:

```
custom-display 0 #<output-port:null>
custom-display 1 #<output-port:null>
custom-print   2 #<printing-port>

custom-display 3 #<output-port:null>
custom-display 4 #<output-port:null>
custom-print   5 #<printing-port>

custom-display 6 #<output-port:null>
custom-display 7 #<printing-port>

custom-display 8 #<output-port:null>
custom-write   9 #<printing-port>
```

while at the command line, the output is:

```
$ racket demo.rkt 
custom-write   0 #<output-port:null>
custom-print   1 #<output-port:redirect>

custom-write   2 #<output-port:null>
custom-print   3 #<output-port:redirect>

custom-display 4 #<output-port:null>
custom-display 5 #<output-port:redirect>

custom-write   6 #<output-port:null>
custom-write   7 #<output-port:redirect>
```